# Blazor webAssembly code in Azure StorageAccount

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

Just watched some blazor [videos](https://youtu.be/noG3rxt38VI) and follow the same step to create and publish first sample app in Azure storage account.
I'm able to run Blazor app without any error in local machine but after publish app in storage account getting below error

Any idea why this error?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a problem with Content-type setting in the storage account.

The mono.wasm content type should be `application/wasm`. Look into the storage account and if it is different set it to `application/wasm`.

[image: Storage Account - File details]

Comment: The exact answer, Thanks Anuraj.